# Cloud Functions error on foreach "Expected catch() or return promise/catch-or-return"

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Firebase functions and can't work out why some code supplied to me seems to now be erroring.  I think it could be that the db isn't perfect now.

code

```
exports.onUpdatePost = functions.firestore
  .document("/posts/{userId}/usersPosts/{postId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const postUpdated = change.after.data();
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const postId = context.params.postId;

    const userFollowersRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("followers")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("userFollowers");

    const querySnapshot = await userFollowersRef.get();

    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const followerId = doc.id;

      admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("timeline")
        .doc(followerId)
        .collection("timelinePosts")
        .doc(postId)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            doc.ref.update(postUpdated);
          }
        });
    });
  });
```

the 'admin' line seems to be the line that functions isn't liking with this error

/Users/chris/Development/buds/functions/index.js
  212:11  error  Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return

Comment: Your code is not dealing with promises correctly.  Firestore functions (as well as all types of background functions) need to return a promise that resolves when all async work is complete.  The promise returned by get() in the loop isn't actually being dealt with properly.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: That seems very much like a (valid) linter warning, not an error from running the code?